# concise but readable way to extract the numerical value after the substring "mode:" in a shell script

Tags: bash, awk, cut, tr

I have this string:

```
DMT           mode 4: 640x480 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:25MHz progressive
```

I want to extract from it the mode number (the part before the first :), which in this example is 4. As you might expect the mode number could be 1 or 2 digits long, and the text that comes before it cannot be relied on being exact the same length of characters.

I have a solution that works:

```
$picked = "DMT           mode 4: 640x480 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:25MHz progressive"
echo $picked | awk -F"mode " '{print $2}' | tr : '\n' | head -n1
```

but I feel like there must be a more elegant way to do this. Elegant and easy to learn now and read again later (thus, probably not involving regex). My dream command would be something like this: **echo $picked | between "mode " ":"**

here's a few more examples to show the range of inputs that would need to be parsable:

```
CEA           mode 7: 720x480 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:27MHz x2 interlaced
CEA  (native)  mode 16: 1920x1080 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:148MHz progressive
DMT           mode 58: 1680x1050 @ 60Hz 16:10, clock:146MHz progressive
```

Comment: `perl -lne 'print /mode (\d\d?):/'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex will be the more direct solution: some options:

```bsh
echo "$picked" | grep -oP '(?<=mode )\d+'
echo "$picked" | grep -oP '(?<=mode )[[:digit:]]+'
```

---

If you don't like the PCRE features:

```bsh
echo "$picked" | grep -oE 'mode [[:digit:]]+' | tr -d 'mode '
```

That `tr` command does not delete the *word* "mode", it delete all the *characters* "m", "o", "d", "e", " ".

---

If you really like [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), iterate over the words until you hit "mode"

```bsh
echo "$picked" | awk '{for (i=1; i<NF; i++) if ($i == "mode") {print $(i+1); exit}}' | tr -d :
```

---

Since you already have the string in a shell variable, how about bash parameter substitution:

```bsh
tmp=${picked#*mode }    # remove up to "mode "
value=${tmp%%:*}        # remove the colon and everything after
```

Then

```bsh
$ declare -p picked tmp value
declare -- picked="DMT           mode 4: 640x480 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:25MHz progressive"
declare -- tmp="4: 640x480 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:25MHz progressive"
declare -- value="4"
```

Referring to [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the manual (and glossing over some of the finer points):

- `${var#pattern}` remove the *shortest prefix* matching the pattern
- `${var##pattern}` remove the *longest prefix* matching the pattern
- `${var%pattern}` remove the *shortest suffix* matching the pattern
- `${var%%pattern}` remove the *longest suffix* matching the pattern

The distinction between "shortest" and "longest" is key. Note that the given string contains multiple colons in the suffix -- using `${tmp%:*}` only removes the *last* colon and following characters.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the  Shell Parameter Expansion bit relevant to this. Makes it much more clear. This is the kind of solution I was looking for. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `perl` or a variant of `grep` that supports PCRE style regular expressions you can pick out the value by matching directly on `mode` followed by one or more digits:

```
grep -oP 'mode\s+\K\d+'
```

I read that you don't like REs, however this is a fairly straightforward pattern that I'll explain here:

- Everything upto `\K` is a lookbehind pattern that must match, but is not included in any result
- `\s` matches whitespace (typically *space* or *tab*); the `+` suffix requires one or more of them
- `\d` matches a digit (`0`..`9`); the `+` suffix requires one or more of them

You could replace `\d+` with `[^:]+` if you knew that the value you wanted could contain non-digit text. Here, the `[^:]` matches anything that is not a colon (`:`).

References

- https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html
- https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html (search for `\K`)

Comment: Thanks for explaining your PCRE regex. indeed it's not so bad, especially compared to the other regex solutions presented, though I still prefer to avoid going down the full regex rabbit hole.

Answer (score 0):

The simple, straightforward `sed` solution is

```
sed -n 's/.*mode \([0-9]*\):.*/\1/p'
```

A single command rather than three (`awk | tr | head`);
if you believe that your solution is easier to read, I can’t help you.

Comment: I don't like the combo of awk, tr, and head, but I don't think your regex is better. Both lack readability, though obviously with enough familiarity either do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I like the Shell Parameter Expansion solution already given, but if you can't use bash, the following AWK chain would work the same way:

```
... |awk -F"mode " '{print$2}' | awk -F: '{print $1}'
```

1st awk invocation splits the string on "mode " and returns what's after it,

2nd invocation splits it on : and returns what's before it.

To me this is more readable than the Bash parameter expansion. It is a lot more wordy, however, and probably slower (though AWK is known to be quite fast, the overhead of starting it twice is going to count against it).